# How to return values without breaking the loop?

Tags: python, function, return-value

I want to know how to return values without breaking a loop in Python.

**Here is an example:**

```
def myfunction():
    list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    print(list)
    total = 0
    for i in list:
        if total < 6:
            return i  #get first element then it breaks
            total += 1
        else:
            break

myfunction()
```

`return` will only get the first answer then leave the loop, I don't want that, I want to return multiple elements till the end of that loop.

How can resolve this, is there any solution?

Comment: you could assign it to a global/class variable, but you can't return without breaking loop that I know of

Comment: This seems like a highly convoluted way of doing something that should be rather simple. Could you explain what you're aiming at with your code? What is the purpose of `myfunction`?

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax Yes I know, but I want to know if there are some ways in order to avoid that

Comment: @Gabriel this is just an example, the real code is in Django and is too long so I didn't post it, but what you should know is that I need to return a lot a certain amount of values so `total += 1` shouldn't be ignored.

Comment: The I guess Jim's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for that, so you could `yield` values from your generator (your function would become a generator after using the `yield`  statement).

See the topics below to get a better idea of how to work with it:

- [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)
- [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)
- [yield and Generators explain's](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/)

An example of using a generator:

```
def simple_generator(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield i
        i += 1

my_simple_gen = simple_generator(3) # Create a generator
first_return = next(my_simple_gen) # 0
second_return = next(my_simple_gen) # 1
```

Also you could create a `list` before the loop starts and `append` items to that list, then return that list, so this list could be treated as list of results "returned" inside the loop.

Example of using list to return values:

```
def get_results_list(n):
    results = []
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        results.append(i)
        i += 1
    return results


first_return, second_return, third_return = get_results_list(3)
```

**NOTE:** In the approach with list you have to know how many values your function would return in `results` list to avoid `too many values to unpack` error

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am searching for

Answer (score 5):

Using a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) is a probable way:

```
def myfunction():
    l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    total = 0
    for i in l:
        if total < 6:
            yield i  #yields an item and saves function state
            total += 1
        else:
            break

g = myfunction()
```

Now you can access all elements returned with `yield i` by calling `next()` on it:

```
>>> val = next(g)
>>> print(v)
a
>>> v = next(g)
>>> print(v)
b
```

Or, in a for loop by doing:

```
>>> for returned_val in myfunction():
...    print(returned_val)
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: The question is kind of outside of what I am asking for but where should I call for `returned_val in myfunction():` in Django, in the template or in the models?

Comment: Call it when you need to use it; I really can't know your setup/what you are trying to achieve to be able to tell you more about it.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is most easily expressed with list slicing:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
>>> l[:6]
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Alternatively create another list which you will return at the end of the function.

```
def myfunction():
    l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
    ret = []

    total = 0
    for i in l:
        if total < 6:
            total += 1
            ret.append(i)

    return ret

myfunction()

# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

A `yield` statement to create a generator is what you want.

[What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python#231855)

Then use the next method to get each value returned from the loop.

```
var = my_func().next()
```

Comment: Good answer. Actually value would be `yielded` and not `returned`