# I have a method / function in python in which i'm trying to get a return value which i can then use as a variable in another function

Tags: python

So i'm trying to learn Python and at the same time write some code to help myself out with some mundane tasks.
so i have a function which works just fine if i use the print statement to display just what i need, but when i replace the "**print**" statement for a "**return**" i only get the first element in the list, i know its because "return" causes the function to exit, but i have no idea how i can get this to return the rest of the elements.
i have tried lots of things and been now reading for hours :( and still getting no further.
objective: To read all the "*.common" files in a directory and then compare them with a text file containing some names, and if they match return the name of the *.common file so i can use it in another function as a variable.
code i have thus far

```
# This method gets the list of common files....
def get_common_files():
    path = (config_home)
    files = []

    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            if '.common' in file:
                files.append(file)

    for f in files:
        return files

new_file = get_common_files()

def build_default_manifest():
    for line in fileinput.FileInput(new_manifest):
        for name in new_file:
            if line.strip() in name:
                print(name) # works as it should and displays all that i need
                return name  # only shows me the first element 


good_name = build_default_manifest()
print(good_name)
```

i hope i've provided all that i need to but if not please feel free to comeback to me...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return values without breaking the loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968634/how-to-return-values-without-breaking-the-loop)

Comment: When you start the for loop `for f in files` you are immediately doing a `return`. So the loop exits right after the first iteration.
You can just do `return files`. You don't have to do the for loop to return since `files` is already a list.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
for f in files:
    return files
```

This is not quite right. There are 2 problems here. First, what this is doing is just returning `files`-- the whole thing, one time. Putting a loop body around the `return` doesn't really make sense. Likely you meant to type `return f`, to iterate over the results.... but that leads to a second problem...

The `return` statement will run the first time it is encountered, causing the function to end, and that's it. So just changing what is returned to `return f` still doesn't quite work: it will return only the first value in `files`.

This is actually really close to a slightly more advanced pattern called a generator. If you replace the above with this:

```
for f in files:
    yield f
```

then your function should work. Explaining why it works is not quite as easy, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)
has some good answers that should help.

Just out of curiosity, did you write this from scratch yourself, or did you follow an example from somewhere? I'm just a bit surprised at how close you got to the generator pattern, apparently unintentionally, and assuming you were not aware of it before.

Comment: "you are only getting the very first value for f in files." Actually, he's getting the whole of `files`. Check the `return` again :-D

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes ahh, you are right! Good eye, i will update.

Answer (score 1):

```
def build_default_manifest():
    for line in fileinput.FileInput(new_manifest):
        for name in new_file:
            if line.strip() in name:
                yield name  

good_name = build_default_manifest()
for name in good_name:

    print(name)
```

like Z4-tier said, sounds like you need a generator.

you can use each element in good_name for a function call like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something here but isn't your for loop (for r, d...) already creating your list called 'files'? So, why not just change:

```
for f in files:
    return files
```

to

```
return files
```

which should just return the entire list?

Comment: thank you all for you prompt replies, its very much appreciated. i shall give them a try and provide feedback @Z4-tier i wrote it myself, based on examples i found.